# different between cd and roscd?

Tags: ros, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,I'm a new learner. Currently learn use Linux and ROS basic command. So what is the different between cd and roscd ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228928/different-between-cd-and-roscd?/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

cd is the standard linux command. roscd however also knows about the installed ros packages, so you can go to a package without having to type (or even know) the exact path. Just try 'roscd you_package'

---

Originally posted by [PickBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/26245/pickbot/) with karma: 123 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-03-13**:
thank you so much!